# Добавить содержимое div в разные input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input hidden type="num" id="add_title_id" value="">
<input type="text" id="add_title" value="">

<div id="search">
<div class="add">ID: <span class="title_id">1</span> TITLE: <span class="title">Тут текст 1</span></div>
<div class="add">ID: <span class="title_id">2</span> TITLE: <span class="title">Тут текст 2</span></div>
<div class="add">ID: <span class="title_id">3</span> TITLE: <span class="title">Тут текст 3</span></div>
<div class="add">ID: <span class="title_id">4</span> TITLE: <span class="title">Тут текст 4</span></div>
<div class="add">ID: <span class="title_id">5</span> TITLE: <span class="title">Тут текст 5</span></div>
</div>
```

Как по клику на `<div class="add">` добавить содержимое из `<span class="title_id">` в `add_title_id`, а `<span class="title">` в `add_title`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(".add").click(function(e) {
  $("#add_title_id").val($(this).find(".title_id").text());
  $("#add_title").val($(this).find(".title").text());
  console.log($("#add_title_id").val());
  /* чтобы ДОБАВИТЬ: 
  $("#add_title_id").val($("#add_title_id").val() + "," + $(this).find(".title_id").text());
  $("#add_title").val($("#add_title").val() + "," + $(this).find(".title").text()); */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input hidden type="num" id="add_title_id" value="">
<input type="text" id="add_title" value="">

<div id="search">
  <div class="add">ID: <span class="title_id">1</span> TITLE: <span class="title">Тут текст 1</span></div>
  <div class="add">ID: <span class="title_id">2</span> TITLE: <span class="title">Тут текст 2</span></div>
  <div class="add">ID: <span class="title_id">3</span> TITLE: <span class="title">Тут текст 3</span></div>
  <div class="add">ID: <span class="title_id">4</span> TITLE: <span class="title">Тут текст 4</span></div>
  <div class="add">ID: <span class="title_id">5</span> TITLE: <span class="title">Тут текст 5</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, вот только мне нужно было уточнить еще то что у `add_title_id` стоит `hidden` и с ним не добавляет :(

Comment: @wwwplaton Как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: Opps... мой косяк, наверное хватит на сегодня и надо идти спать.  Спасибо.